# How to use custom exceptions from packages in your excepts clauses?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, pygsheets

I have a script which uses the package pygsheets to upload a dataframe to Google sheets. If the dataframe is empty, the following error appears:

```
InvalidArgumentValue: provide either cells or values, not both
```

So, I have been trying to use a try-except structure to pass when the dataframe is empty, but raising an exception if any other error happens. The code is the following:

```
try:
    pygsheets code
except InvalidArgumentValue:
    pass
except:
    raise Exception
```

However, when I try to execute the lines above, it throws me the following errors:

```
NameError: name 'InvalidArgumentValue' is not defined
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you imported pygsheets in the usual fashion

```
import pygsheets
```

your code should reference exceptions contained in that package using the usual syntax for referencing member classes of another package, like

```
try:
    pygsheets code
except pygsheets.InvalidArgumentValue:
    pass
except:
    raise Exception
```